# The measurability of $f(x) = \sum_{r_n \leq x} \frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] = \{ r_1, r_2, \ldots \}$ be an enumeration of the rationals and let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
f(x) = \sum_{r_n \leq x} \dfrac{1}{2^n}
$$

I need to show that $f$ is measurable. Maybe it is easy, but I don't have any idea to how do this. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: It's increasing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is the pointwise limit of the sequence of functions:

$$f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n} \chi_{[r_n,1]}(x).$$

The $f_N$ are measurable because they are simple functions. Do you know how to prove that the pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable?

Comment: Yes, I do! I think that your sequence solves the problem. The other question I ask to you: Is $f$ Lebesgue-integrable?

Comment: @Gauss Sure. Its integral is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-r_n}{2^n}$, which is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks! It is correct my idea? First I proved that the set of discontinuous points of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ which has null measure, therefore $f$ is integrable.

Comment: That does work out, but you have to be careful, because for instance $\chi_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}$ has set of discontinuity points all of $[0,1]$. One clever argument for this case is that $f$ is increasing, so it can only have at most countably many discontinuities by a standard result. So this actually proves $f$ is Riemann integrable. Proving it is Lebesgue integrable is much easier (again it is measurable by a general result, and its integral is finite because it is bounded and the space has finite measure).

Comment: I will think about this. Thanks for your help!